# How to display a collection in View of ASP.NET MVC Razor project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, uicollectionview

How to display a collection in View of ASP.NET MVC Razor project?

My Model and View is below. For one person i've to display Many tests on the screen. Thanks in Advance

```
namespace UI.Models
{
public class SuperStudent
{      
    public string FullName { get; set; }      

    public ICollection<TestDetail> CandidateTestDetails { get; set; }
}
public class TestDetail
{
    public DateTime TestDate { get; set; }
    public string RegNum { get; set; }     
}
```

}

---

View

```
@model IEnumerable<UI.Models.SuperStudent>
   <p>
      @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
    <tr>       
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FullName)
        </th>     
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
     <tr>
        <td>
         Print all test details            
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
     </table>
```

Answer (score 6):

For one person your view must be like :

```
@model UI.Models.SuperStudent
<h2>@Model.FullName</h2>
<table class="table">
<tr>       
    <th>
       TestDate 
    </th>  
   <th>
       RegNum
    </th>   
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model.CandidateTestDetails ) {
 <tr>
    <td>
     @item.TestDate             
    </td>
   <td>
     @item.RegNum
    </td>
</tr>
}
 </table>
```

Comment: Thanks Azad, I don't have the points to give your answer +1. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The code works the same inside a loop as it does outside the loop.  Just reference the loop item.  For example:

```
@foreach (var student in Model) {
  @foreach (var test in student.CandidateTestDetails) {
    <tr>
      <td>@test.RegNum</td>
    </tr>
  }
}
```

That would output just the `RegNum` value.  You can also make use of things like `DisplayNameFor` by referencing an element in the collection:

```
@foreach (var student in Model) {
  @foreach (var test in student.CandidateTestDetails) {
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => student.CandidateTestDetails.First().RegNum)<br />
        @test.RegNum
      </td>
    </tr>
  }
}
```

While *intuitively* it may seem that this could fail if `Model` is empty (since `First()` would throw an exception), it doesn't *actually* execute `First()` on the collection.  The engine simply uses that to reflect into the model returned by `First()` to determine the display name.

Given this, you can construct the markup however you wish for those items.  If it's complex enough, you might even create a partial view for just an item in that collection and render that partial view in the loop by passing the `item` value to the partial view.

Comment: Thanks David. I tried ur first solution but it didn't work,  Error  'UI.Models.SuperStudent' does not contain a definition for 'RegNum' and no extension method 'RegNum' accepting a first argument of type 'UI.Models.SuperStudent' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Sreejith: Looks like I misunderstood the structure of the models.  (Hint: Use meaningful names such as `student` instead of `item`.)  I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks David, I don't have the points to give your answer +1. Thanks for the quick response.