# Display ICollection in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm developing a project on ASP.NET MVC5 and using EF6.
I have the following classes, with a **one-to-many relationship** between Author and Book, where an Author can have multiple Books and a Book can only belong to one Author:

**Models:**

```
public class Author 
{
   public int AuthorId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book 
{
   public int BookId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public int? AuthorId { get; set; }
   public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

I have generated the approppiate controller with views using EF and now, I want to display for each Author the corresponding associated books' names, in Details.cshtml view.

The **Controller**:

```
// GET: Authors/Details/5
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Author author = await db.Authors.FindAsync(id);

    if (author == null)
    {
       return HttpNotFound();
    }
       return View(author);
}
```

My **Details.cshtml** as follows:

```
@model MyApp.Models.Author

<div>
    <h4>Author Info</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt style="font-size:20px">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd style="font-size:20px">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>

        <dt style="font-size:20px">
            Associated Books
        </dt>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Books)
        {
            <dd>
                @item.Name
            </dd>
        }

    </dl>
</div>
```

But this generates the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Exception
>   Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

I have followed the answer to this similar question ([How to display a collection in View of ASP.NET MVC Razor project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494718/how-to-display-a-collection-in-view-of-asp-net-mvc-razor-project)) but, obviously, with no success. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Obviously Books is null... Use Include

Comment: @Selvin it may be pretty obvious to you but maybe for others it isn't. Do you really think I would even bother to post this question here if all it took was a simple, quick, naive search on the Internet?

Comment: @Selvin Well, all I can tell you is this, I tried and did the research to the best of my knowledge. I am sorry if the question bothered you somehow but this is the truth. Maybe with more years of experience I will learn how to properly search for answers to my problems but so far, I thought this was the best place to ask for some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your View is perfectly fine.

The problem is that **EF does not load related entities by default** (for performance reasons), so the `Books` property on your `Author` will remain null.

You have to manually tell the context to load the books as well, by using `.Include`. For example:

```
Author author = await db.Authors.Include(a => a.Books).SingleOrDefault(a => a.AuthorId == id);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Marcell! :) Will accept the answer as soon as I can!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help:)